# Trying to find a nice looking way to transform this array using functional programming style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

Given an array of objects like this:

```
[
    { x: 'x1', y: 'y1' },
    { y: 'y2', z: 'z1' },
    { z: 'z2', x: 'x2' } 
]
```

I want to produce an object like this:

```
{
    x: [ 'x1', 'x2' ],
    y: [ 'y1', 'y2' ],
    z: [ 'z1', 'z2' ] 
}
```

I'm looking for a functional programming style solution in JavaScript using ES5 or underscore.js functions like map/reduce/etc.

Comment: You mean ES5? Not that it matters. I think you'd use `reduce`, not sure though

Comment: This is my poor attempt at making it fully functional: http://jsfiddle.net/9ppgs/

Comment: You're right, they have been around since ES5. And yes, reduce seems like the way to go (reducing an array to a single object), but I couldn't find a nice solution earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?

```
var array = [ { x: 'x1', y: 'y1' },
              { y: 'y2', z: 'z1' },
              { z: 'z2', x: 'x2' }
            ];

var result = array.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
        if (!res[k])
            res[k] = [];
        res[k].push(obj[k]);
    });
    return res;
}, {});
```

Note that I think most people would find this significantly more confusing than the looping method:

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var k in array[i]) {
        if (!result[k])
            result[k] = [];
        result[k].push(array[i][k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I forget about using `Object.keys()` to take advantage of Array methods; otherwise I can only think of using a `for` loop (like your second example)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using underscore

```
var _ = require("underscore");

var arr = [
    { x: 'x1', y: 'y1' },
    { y: 'y2', z: 'z1' },
    { z: 'z2', x: 'x2' }
];


var data = _.reduce(_.flatten(_.map(arr, _.pairs),true), function (memo, value) {
        if (!memo.hasOwnProperty(value[0])) {
            memo[value[0]] = [];
        }
        memo[value[0]].push(value[1]);
        return memo;
    },
    {});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather unconventional approach using Underscore's [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) that completely ignores the property names and goes by the first character of the values:

```
var arr = [
    { x: 'x1', y: 'y1' },
    { y: 'y2', z: 'z1' },
    { z: 'z2', x: 'x2' }
];
return _.groupBy( _.flatten(_.map(arr, _.values)), 0);
```

A completely functional approach would be using `reduce` to do the grouping:

```
return _.reduce( arr, function(m, obj) {
    return _.reduce( obj, function(m, val, key) {
        (m[key] || (m[key] = [])).push(val);
        return m;
    }, m);
}, {});
```

Comment: Heh nice one with the groupBy, but the fact that the values started with the same letter as the key was just to make the example easy to graps, of course the values could be anything ;)